# Rails set model attribute if blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model that has an attribute called `country`. This attribute is set by a method called `methodA`.

Somewhere else in my code I may try to access User's `country` attribute and it might be blank if `methodA` never ran.

What I'm looking for is to run `methodA` if I try to access User's `country` attribute **and it's blank**.

I tried something like that in my Model :

```
def country
  c = read_attribute(:country).presence

  if c.blank?
    methodA
  else
    return c
  end
end
```

But I get an error when it first runs. If I reload the page, `country` has been set on the previous run (even tho the error) and it's all good.

I would love it to work on the first run and avoid the error page tho...

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can just call `super`

```
def country
  super.presence || "do whatever"
end
```

`presence` will check `present?` and if `present?` it will return its receiver; otherwise it returns a false-y value (nil).

Remember that if possible you should be setting a database default.

Comment: So it should look like this `super.presence || methodA` ?

Comment: Yes — Ruby will evaluate anything after the `||`

Comment: I tried it and i still get the same error of my previous "solution". Check OP : `But I get an error when it first runs. If I reload the page, country has been set on the previous run (even tho the error) and it's all good.`

Also check the solution I exposed on my 2nd post.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve my goal using this :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_find :check_country

  def check_country
    if country.blank?
      methodA
    end
  end

  def methodA
    ...code
  end
end
```

It does work but I'm not sure if this is ideal... Because `check_country` will be executed everythime a User is fetched... Even if `country` is set.
I would prefer it to run only if `country` is blank.

Any idea ?